# Get ASP MVC4 and Angular 5 HttpClient to work together

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc-4, http-post, angular5

Since I migrated from Angular 2.X to Angular 5.X, I have been having some trouble with performing HTTP Requests. I'll Start from the top.

Here I have some test MVC Controller and a test Action:

```
public class AccountController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ObjResultFunc Test()
    {
        return new ObjResultFunc(() => new { Data = "Some Text" });
    }
}
```

and the config:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.EnableCors();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Then, here is the current AngularJS 2.X implementation of the Http module that worked:

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { activeUrlToken } from '../app/providers'

import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';


@Injectable()
export class MVCAngularDataService {



  constructor(private http: Http, @Inject(activeUrlToken) private API_URL: string) {

  }

  private handleError(error: Response | any) {
    console.error('ApiService::handleError', error);
    return Observable.throw(error);
  }

  public post(controller: string, action: string, data: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http
      .post(this.API_URL + '/' + controller + '/' + action, data)
      .map(response => {
        return response;
      })
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

}
```

Also note that the `this.API_URL` points to:

```
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core'
export const activeUrlToken = new InjectionToken('activeUrlToken');
export const activeUrl = 'http://localhost:3144/api';
```

And calling a test function worked:
`this.mvcAngularService.post('Account', 'Test', null).subscribe(data => { console.log(data); });`

Then I adapted the `MVCAngularDataService` to use the `HttpClient` module in Angular 5.X since Http no longer wanted to work and it is recommended to use the HttpClient now in 5.X, which looks as follow:

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { activeUrlToken } from '../app/providers'
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class MVCAngularDataService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, @Inject(activeUrlToken) private API_URL: string) {

  }

  private handleError(error: Response | any) {
    console.error('ApiService::handleError', error);
    return Observable.throw(error);
  }

  public post(controller: string, action: string, data: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http
      .post(this.API_URL + '/' + controller + '/' + action, data)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

}
```

Now whenever I try to perform a simple post, I get a `404 - Not Found` Error:

[image: 404]

[image: Network Details]

What am I missing? I have a strong suspicion that the problem lies at the MVC server side of things but have no idea where to start looking.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your `nodu_modules` folder, Then check for `@angular/common/http` it was happened with me my @angular/common/http was missing.